# Install package along with all the dependencies offline

Tags: package-management, software-installation

Right now I have 2 computers:

1. Has connection to the internet and has installed package `A`.
2. Doesn't have connection to the WEB. On this PC I need to install package `A`.

I decided to download all needed packages using first PC and transfer them to the second PC via USB. I have searched how to get all needed packages for some `deb` installation and [here's what I've found](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/517).

But when I run:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install A | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 > downloads.list
```

on first PC I got empty file because this package is already installed there (and I don't want to uninstall it).

Also package A is very complicated and depends on package `B` which depends on package `C` and package `C` is not installed on the second PC.

So how can I download all needed packages? Or is there any other way of installing it?

Comment: I think you can generate a download script with Synaptic. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

Answer (score 3):

**keryx**
It's a gui application for installing packages on complete offline system.

https://launchpad.net/keryx

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/keryx-offline-package-installation-made-easy-in-ubuntu

.............................................................................................

**apt-offline** : CLI
Let offPC is the offline computer and onPC is the online computer.

1. Install `apt-offline` on offPC
2. Download `apt-offline` from onPC. (try: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/apt-offline/download)
3. Copy and paste the '.deb' file to offPC
4. Install it by opening it. (or using `sudo dpkg -i '/path/to/file/apt-offline.deb'`)
5. Generate update link file [offPC]
   `sudo apt-offline set /tmp/updateee --update`

   > Generating database of files that are needed for an update.
6. Download update files using link file [onPC]
   `sudo apt-offline get /tmp/updateee`

   > Downloading http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2.
   >   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2 done.
   >   Downloading http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.bz2.
   >   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.bz2 done.
   >   Downloading http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2.
   >   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2 done..........
   >
   > Downloaded data to /tmp/apt-offline-downloads-5942
7. Add downloaded update files to offPC
   `sudo apt-offline install /tmp/apt-offline-downloads-5942/`

   > gpgv: Signature made Fri 21 Jun 2013 02:08:43 PM UTC using DSA key ID 437D05B5
   >   gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key "
   >   gpgv: Signature made Fri 21 Jun 2013 02:08:43 PM UTC using RSA key ID C0B21F32
   >   gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) "
8. Generate package link file [offPC]
   `sudo apt-offline set /tmp/package --update`
9. Download package files using link file [onPC]
   `sudo apt-offline get /tmp/package`
10. Add downloaded package files to offPC
    `sudo apt-offline install /tmp/apt-offline-downloads-5942/`
11. Install package
    Open terminal `sudo apt-get install package_name`  or
    open software center, install package.

**Note1:** Before using the file (updateee, package), you have to transfer the file from offPC to onPC (using Pen drive or something). Also copy the folder containing downloaded file to onPC to offPC.

**Note2:** If you get an error

> E: Unable to locate package package_name

while installing, that means the package is not known to the offPC. This occurs due to many reason. such as Personal package maintained be private parties. (Search PPA)
Try add **software sources** by opeing software sources (from unity), then tick on *Universe* and other filds

Answer (score 3):

## Cube

> Cube is an offline package management system that enables Linux distribution users (Ubuntu, Linux Mint and other APT-based systems) to have applications installed to their system even without internet connection. Just run the cube in your Linux system, create your project in it, paste your project together with cube in a flashdrive and fly away to any computer with internet connection, open the cube and select your project, update your applications and download any applications you want, go back to your Linux system and install it directly. And that’s it! You can now use your new application :).

You can download cube at its launchpad page : https://launchpad.net/camicricube

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the methods here?

[Installing packages without an Internet connection](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection)

Mentioned there,

## Keryx

(mentioned earlier by answerer @totti)

> Keryx is a portable, cross-platform package manager for APT-based
>   (Ubuntu, Debian) systems. It provides a graphical interface for
>   gathering updates, packages, and dependencies for offline computers.
>   Keryx is free and open source. You can get Keryx here: 
>   https://launchpad.net/keryx

## Synaptic package download script

> Here's how: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic/PackageDownloadScript

---

... Not mentioned at that site:

### AptMedium

Seems the best tailored for your use case, unfortunately super immature. 
[link](http://wiki.debian.org/AptMedium)

### apt-offline

Looks like the best command-line tool for the job. Unfortunately, the "howto"s always start with the assumption that you have "apt-offline" already installed on the offline machine, ignoring the obvious question of how it would have got there in the first place. 
[link](http://alioth.debian.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=2898)

Answer (score 1):

Check this folder `/var/cache/apt/archives` this should effectively contain all packages downloaded during the installation of package A, copy paste the same contents to `/var/cache/apt/archives` of second computer. try apt-get install package a

For this to work you have must have at least once did `apt-get update` (For getting package lists for reference on apt)

Else you can try `dpkg -i packageA.deb` and see missing packages and install the ones from the archives folder. (This method is ridiculous)

I had used apt cds before, try googling for creating apt cds from existing system.

Comment: I don't think that this is safe way - this solution may crash Ubuntu on second PC.

Comment: Why would it not be safe? You need to make sure both machines run the same architecture and Ubuntu version, of course.