# How do I use a Huawei 4g dongle?

Tags: networking, drivers, 4g

I'm a new comer to Linux. I'm going to install Lubuntu (which is the best for my PC specs).
Now the problem is how do I connect to internet.

I don’t have a WiFi connection. I connect to internet by my dongle (a Huawei dongle and it is customized by MOBILY 4G).

It works fine with Windows because the it has a .exe file to install the software. But in Linux I can’t install .exe files without something like wine.(As I know)

So what can I do?

Model number of my dongle - E3276s - 920

Also mention how can I update my drivers.
(The transparency effects don’t work.)

Comment: Also asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/help-a-newbie-internet-and-drivers-problem/1269

Comment: Since this is an already tested and working USB modem, have you tried simply plugging it in while running Lubuntu to see if it works? You can test with a [bootable USB stick](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). I've used several Huawei 4G USB modems and they 'just work'. Ubuntu recognized it as a modem and it connected immediately. If you change SIMs, visit 192.168.8.1 for its settings page (check the documentation but that's probably the address).

Comment: Thnx for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ubuntu. First of all I brief you about the fact that Wine in Ubuntu or any or Linux distro  is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications. You need not to install any .exe driver in Ubuntu.

1. First install `modeswitch`. Open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and type

   ```
   sudo apt-get update     
   sudo apt-get -y install usb-modeswitch
   ```

   It will ask for your password. enter password. After that plug in your usb modem and run following command in terminal:

   ```
   lsusb
   ```

   Now your modem should be present in the list.

   Here is the further solution to add your modem as modem shared by [johado](https://askubuntu.com/users/474204/johado) in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557137/configuring-huawei-e3276-modem) post for

   Open terminal and type

   ```
   sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/70-usb-modeswitch.rules
   ```

   after this open in terminal copy and past following line(note in terminal you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save.

   ```
   # custom udev rules for UMTS modems
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="14fe", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'"


   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1506", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'modprobe option && echo 12d1 1506 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
   ```

   I saved this as `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-usb-modeswitch.rules`.
2. For updating your driver and software run following in terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

   ```
   sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
   ```

   then update software from update manager.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: Could you explein what to do please.As I'm a new comer I don't understand what to do.

Comment: I have edited answer step wise detailed. Hope you understand now.

Comment: Thnx for your support.

Comment: If it worked for you mark answer as correct. Whenever you find answer to your problem. mark/ upvote that answer helps others to get most suitable solution for their problem.

Comment: I tried that.But it didn't work.To do that I think I should have connected to the internet. So I plugged a wi-fi adapter(my pc doesn't have built in wi-fi) and tried to connect with giving hotspot by my phone.It also didn't work. As I'm running lubuntu using my usb drive, I decided to install it on my hdd.Now it's still installing.What should I do next.

Comment: you can download the .deb package of  usb-modeswitch from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/. For instructions regarding installing .deb files/ other packages you can refer apt-offline or Keryx on https://askubuntu.com/questions/306971/install-package-along-with-all-the-dependencies-offline

Comment: I did that it also didn't work.

Comment: When i runned lsusb code it shows me the modem. With a id 12dq:1501(as I remember).I can't update my drivers without having a internet connection to that pc my 802.11n wifi adapter also doesn't work.

Comment: What to do please help.Is this a problem with lubuntu.

Comment: Please read this post https://trick77.com/setting-up-huawei-e3276-150-4g-lte-usb-modem-ubuntu-server-desktop/   and check dmesg -T. Hope this post will help you setup.