# Install dongle driver of DIGISOL DG-BA3321 3.75G in lubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 20.04, usb-modem

I have an old dongle of [DIGISOL (DG-BA3321, 3.75G Broadband Modem Adapter 21 Mbps)](https://www.amazon.in/Digisol-DG-BA3321-3-75G-Broadband-Adapter/dp/B00M7RU8YC). It works fine in windows pc. There is a simple exe set up file in the dongle rom and installing it does the work. But for linux there is an installation package (probably) but I do not quite know how to install it to make it work. The dongle rom files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CRD3hKE_atgVYr_08-aeG-OGtT6ZElfK?usp=sharing). The modem is also has a built in card reader. So when I plug it in Lubuntu recognizes it as a rom (containing the dongle drivers in no sd card is inside it) or as a usb-storage device but it is not recognized as a modem automatically.

My question is quite similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249108/how-do-i-use-a-huawei-4g-dongle) but there the model number is different and it is after all a different device.

Please guide me in a step by step manner as to what to do.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about model ?

Comment: Your Drive files seems not be shared publicly.

Comment: @KKPatel I have updated my question

Comment: Thanks. I can see you have .pkg package which can be used for solaris but not Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no .deb installer available or driver files available for Ubuntu.

Comment: @KKPatel isn't there any other way out? like the answers to the other question were saying. Are they all specific to that usb modem or generic and could be considered for my model as well.